# Auto update script js/svg

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, svg

I can not fix this why it update only the last tag(id), not one-by-one
This i my first fun() which start with onload of file.svg:

```
function refresh()
{
    totalUpdate();
    var t=setTimeout("refresh()",2000);
}
```

And here are the functions:

```
function totalUpdate()
{
    //user array with elements on user ID
    var tags = document.getElementById("user").getElementsByTagName("circle");

    for(var i=0;i<=document.getElementById('user').childElementCount;i++)
    {   

        var tag=null,id=null,url=null;
        id=tags[i].getAttribute("id");
        tag=tags[i];
        url="get.php?id="+id;
        $.get(url,function(data){
            updateDATA(tag, data);
        });
    }
}

function updateDATA(tag, data){
    data=data.split(" ");
    //data[0]=>x data[1]=>y data[2]=>data
    var x,y;

    //$x=(($x*1000000-$bx)*$svgwidth/$mx*-1)*1000000;
    x=((data[0]*1000000-20959350)*352/3615);
    y=((data[1]*1000000-41989603)*662/5391)*-1;

    tag.setAttribute("cx",x+4);
    tag.setAttribute("cy",y+5);
}
```

SVG body:

```
<g id='user'>


    <circle class="user" id="1" cy="329" cx="179" r="5" style="fill:red">
        <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>


    <circle class="user" id="2" cy="366" cx="189" r="5" style="fill:green">
        <animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </circle>
  </g>
```

Functions updating only the second element not both of them!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has lexical scoping and `$.get` is asynchronous, so by the time `updateDATA` is invoked `tag` references the last element in the list `tags`. You can fix this by wrapping the async call with a function.

Check out this demo where `$.get` is replaced by `setTimeout`: http://jsfiddle.net/GuGb4/